# How can i use Opera web browser as remote access application?

Tags: 11.04, windows, remote-desktop, opera

My Ubuntu 11.04 has Opera web browser. And Behind complex NAT i have another PC with Ubuntu 11.04. In that PC i saw Skype works.

Now PC1 would like to connect PC2. Without using TeamViewer/Logmein.com nor UltraVNC is best solution for this case.

Any idea? How can we do this with Opera Web Browser in Ubuntu to CrossPlatform remote access?

**Scenario 1:**

- PC2 will open Opera webbrowser
- PC2 will click let them login or let anyone login
- PC1 received a phone call, user of Ubuntu open his tools
- PC1 connects to PC2 (without involving any commercial paid services, like Skype NAT/Firewall technique)

Appreciate your advise, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess for this specific scenario you have to write your own server. Or you can use VNC server controlled with shell scripts. and you can always configure vnc's xsession in such a way that on startup it automatically starts opera.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear to me what you want to do, nor why your webbrowser is involved. Do you want to run skype on pc2 from pc1? In that case you can setup an ssh server on pc2. If the remote user logs in using `ssh pc2 -X`, he can use skype on pc1.